# Nightly truncating all cache_* tables? Good or bad?

Tags: 7, caching, performance, cron

I'm having some issues on various D7 sites with some cache tables growing stupidly large (e.g `cache_metadata` or `cache_menu`) which then makes `drush cc all` very slow (more than 1 minute).

Do you think that there is any problem if I setup a nightly linux cronjob which will be truncating `cache` and `cache_*` tables apart from `cache_form`? And after that I plan on executing a `drush cc all` for safety.

p.s I do not plan on investigating and trying to fix the root cause that makes those tables grow large.

Comment: You can also use a different cache backend for some tables, for example memcache (https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) or redis (https://www.drupal.org/project/redis). It can works faster than sql cache tables. 

In my projects I use memcache and the experience is good.

Answer (score 0):

Cron job to truncate the tables might cause some metadata locks due to the TRUNCATE command being a DDL statement; depends on how busy your server is. What [APDQC](https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc) does is a table rename swap and then truncate; if you did something similar then you should be ok. APDQC will also use gzip to make the table sizes smaller; something that would be a benefit in your case. Without compression our DB cache tables would take about 50GB, they now take about 12gb.